# How to get value from Django BigAutoField

Tags: python, django

Tyring to get a value out of `django.db.models.fields.BigAutoField` for reference. I can't seem to convert it to a `int` and if I convert to a `str` I just get `(<django.db.models.fields.BigAutoField>,)`. I've tried to find some documentation but can't seem to see any way of getting a value out.

Comment: remove the trailing comma at the end of the line when you define the field.

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: I've tried `int(instance.id)` and `str(instance.id)` and also unpacking the tuple then trying to pass as an int.

Comment: @w_jay: the problem is where you *defined* the `id` field.

Comment: Ah dam yeah I've just seen, somehow I left a trailing comma then